# Install SMBv1 client on win10 without admin or compromising security?

Tags: network-share, windows-10, server-message-block, network-security

This relates to [Sending files from win10 to SMBv1 server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/998045/sending-files-from-win10-to-smbv1-server) but it is broader. Feel free to edit/move/remove.

Windows 10 update 1803 removes all functionality of SMBv1 unless explicitly set so by admin, by using the windows procedure for installing extra components.

Since then (April/2018) , all of a sudden lots and lots of industrial machines have lost network connection because their controllers used SMBv1 (passwordless) for uploading data to the machine. Think of an industrial printer where you "dump" the files to print onto its primitive controller. A lot of industrial machinery relies on SMBv1! And I would guess in sensitive areas like military! In lots of cases there is no choice of upgrade. There is even no choice of setting a password for the file transfer. This is not as bad as it sounds in some settings because the machine and the designer are side-by-side in a shop. But yes, security is an issue strictly speaking.

My question is how to continue *sending-only* files to these machines from windows-10 using SMBv1 (passwordless). I have no concern about the security of the receiving machine. But, I *prefer* not to compromise the security of the sender (windows-10) machine, without even admin rights. Will I be right that an `smbclient`-like 3rd-party application installed on windows-10 will be a safe option just for *sending* files?